# Python 3.4 buildozer android sdk download fail

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python 3.4 and i have installed kivy and buildozer succesfully but when i run the command "buildozer android debug". I am getting the following output. Please help to debug the issue.

```
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/paul/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.8.4
# Android SDK is missing, downloading
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.15', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 957, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 157, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 365, in install_platform
    self._install_android_sdk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 235, in _install_android_sdk
    raise SystemError('Unsupported platform: {0}'.format(platform))
SystemError: Unsupported platform: linux
```

Comment: That error shouldn't happen: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/buildozer/targets/android.py#L231 - could you check that code in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py`? Maybe you are using an older version with a bug in that check.

Comment: hi @ThiefMaster let me check it out thanks

Comment: I have runned that code but no output :-(

Comment: Your are not supposed to run the file, you should open it in an editor and check the source code around line 235.

Comment: sorry for being slow i have understood what you were saying i have edited the code and it is running thanks @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of bulldozer ist too old. There is [this commit](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/commit/373f8e22456003f6b1579da44afcbab45223d4a9) fixing the exact issue you have:

```
- elif platform in ('linux2', 'linux3'):
+ elif platform.startswith('linux'):
```

Upgrading to a more recent version will solve your problem.

Comment: I am getting a new error could you help me with it?

Comment: Please don't edit the code. Update to the newest version of buildozer instead!

Comment: i have tried "sudo pip3 install --upgrade buildozer" the output is it is the recent updated version

Comment: hey @ThiefMaster this is the new error i am getting follow link ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337393/buildozer-package-available-for-installation-or-update-error