# Buildozer package available for installation or update error

Tags: android, ubuntu, python-3.x

This is the display that I am getting when building my Android app. please help!

Packages available for installation or update: 3

```
id: 1 or "tools"
     Type: Tool
     Desc: Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.2
----------
id: 2 or "platform-tools"
     Type: PlatformTool
     Desc: Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1
----------
id: 3 or "addon-google_gdk-google-19"
     Type: Addon
     Desc: Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 8
           By Google Inc.
           Preview of the Glass Development Kit
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 19
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.16-dev', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 959, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 157, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 383, in install_platform
    self._install_android_packages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 339, in _install_android_packages
    self._android_update_sdk('tools,platform-tools')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 303, in _android_update_sdk
    from buildozer.libs.pexpect import EOF
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/libs/pexpect.py", line 81
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

i went into the same trouble. Actually buildozer seems to do the update, just not saying that it does.

So just wait:)

Comment: I'm on 2.7 and I had this problem too. I figured I could google it while I was waiting as I suspected that I just had to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 does not support `except Foo, bar` but only `except Foo as bar`. So `buildozer` seems to contain a library which is not compatible with Python 3.

Better contact the developer of buildozer - that will be much more helpful to both you and that tool than posting about it on SO.